# Creating a subview that stays on screen regardless of viewController

Tags: iphone, ipad, admob, viewcontroller, adwhirl

Is there a way that I could create a subview that will stay on the screen even as the user moves back and forth between the different viewControllers in the app?

I have a game where each level is a separate .h/.m/.xib viewController, but I would like to release a free version with ads - trying to figure out how I can get the ads to persist on screen regardless of the viewController currently shown, so that I am not removing and adding a new ad each time the level switches.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you add your view to your application's window AFTER adding the NavigationController (or TabBarController, or whatever your root view controller is)'s view, then it will 'float' above all the other views.

Comment: presentModalViewController will cover this view.

Comment: Thanks Ben! For those that want a little more: I created my adview in the root ViewController, then every I added a new subview to the screen, I immediately ran: [self.view bringSubviewToFront:self.adView]; to make sure that my ad was visible in front of any new view I brought on to the screen